# C Programming - Multi-line comments

Tags: c, syntax, comments, line

How to ignore the multi-line comment symbols ***inside*** another multi-line comment?

Say I want to put the entire code in comments so that I can test other things in my code

```
/* This is my first comment */
printf("\n This is my first print command");

/* This is my second comment */
printf("\n This is my second print command");
```

If I do

```
/* 

/* This is my first comment */
printf("\n This is my first print command");

/* This is my second comment */
printf("\n This is my second print command");

*/
```

this is creating error.

Comment: Most modern IDEs have tools which can aid you in doing a block comment, all with the single click of a mouse.  As the answer-comment below says, you probably can't do this.

Comment: Also, that's a good reason not to use multi line comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you *expect* here is the multi-line comments to be *nested*.

Quoting directly from the standard `C11`, chapter §6.4.9,

> Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters `/*`
>   introduce a comment. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify
>   multibyte characters and to find the characters `*/` that terminate it. <sup>83)</sup>

and the footnote,

> 83 ) **Thus, `/* ... */` comments do not nest.**

As a workaround, you can use the conditional compilation block as

```
#if 0
.
.
.
.
#endif
```

to have a whole block *commented out*.

Comment: Thank you :) .. StackOverflow is adding things to my learning . Happy about it..    I never used # if 0 ..... #endif . So thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is

```
#if 0
/Code that needs to be commented/
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to comment out some code containing itself comments.

You can use conditionnal compilation for this:

```
#if 0
/* This is my first comment */
printf("\n This is my first print command");

/* This is my second comment */
printf("\n This is my second print command");
#endif
```

Everything between `#if 0` and `#endif` will be ignored by the compiler, just if it was a comment.